# Do 6/3 proportional valves like this exist?

Tags: hydraulics, valves

[image]

Like a directional valve but used to select either pair of supply and return. Could be done with two regular 5/3 valves, but it would be nice to use only a single valve. Does something like it exist?

Comment: Yes.  But a simple search on the internet with the exact same words as your question would yield results.

Comment: NMech I did. But clearly you didn't, or you misunderstood the question.

Comment: Search on manufacturers like Bosch Rexroth - they make valves like this.

Comment: @SolarMike Which search term do you suggest I use?

Comment: What are you looking for?

Comment: @SolarMike I am looking for a valve that functions as the symbol I posted, which I should say, I made it myself to illustrate the point. It would actually surprise me if this valve actually existed.

Comment: So how would you describe it? Using words... Or, how do the hydraulic valve manufacturers list hydraulic valves? so they can be identified?

Comment: @SolarMike The valve should proportionally open to either of two different sets of supplies and returns, hence the four ports on the underside in the symbol.

Comment: So how would you describe it using the method that the hydraulic valve manufacturers use to describe proportional valves?

Comment: look at [MHS](https://www.mhs.co.uk/hydraulic-item.php?key=1759)

Comment: Normally, you would have a selector valve and a separate proportional control. https://asktractormike.com/product/hydraulic-diverter-valve-for-tractor/